# For which values of $a$ is the system asymptotic stable?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, stability-theory, characteristic-polynomial

> Consider the system of differential equations
> $$x'=\bigg[ \begin{matrix} a & 2 \\ a & 1
> \end{matrix} \bigg] \cdot \bigg[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \bigg]$$
> For what values of $a$ is the system asymptotic stable?
>
> Investigate if the system is stable for $a=-1$ and for $a \geq 0$

My idea was to find the characteristic polynomial.
$$P(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda E) =(a-\lambda)(1-\lambda)-2a=\lambda^2-\lambda(1+a)-a$$

If the system has to be asymptotic stable, the solution must satisfy $x(t) \rightarrow0$ for $t \rightarrow 0$

We try to solve the characteristic equation:
$$ \lambda^2-\lambda(1+a)-a =0 $$
and get
$$\lambda=\frac{1}{2} +\frac{a}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{a^2+6a+1}}{2} \: \: \: \text{or} \: \: \: \lambda=\frac{1}{2} +\frac{a}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{a^2+6a+1}}{2}$$

But I'm not sure where to go from here. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is asymptotically stable iff the real part of all the eigenvalues are negative (because that part leads to an exponential expression $e^{\mathrm{Re}(\lambda) t}$).

For *two* variables, this is equivalent to the *trace* of the matrix being negative and the *determinant* positive. You can see this by taking the different cases: $$\mathrm{Tr}(A)=\lambda+\mu\quad(=r+iv+r-iv=2r),\qquad \det(A)=\lambda\mu\quad(=r^2+v^2)$$

Thus, stable solutions occur when $$a+1<0,\qquad a-2a>0$$ $$\therefore\quad a<-1$$

---

Note: Your solution has an error in the characteristic polynomial (sign of last term).